# Can I install Azure SDK over command line?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, windows-server-2012-r2, azure, vagrant

I am attempting to use Vagrant to provision a Windows Server box for an integrated development environment.

This environment depends on the Azure SDK.

Is there a way for me to write a script that I can use when provisioning this box to download and install the Azure SDK?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try pre-installing the Azure SDK in the Vagrant base image (called 'box')

https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/getting-started/boxes.html

```
Vagrant uses a base image to quickly clone a virtual machine. 
These base images are known as "boxes" in Vagrant
```

That way you have it installed and configured prior to provisioning.